# Join tables with Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have models `Article` and `Language` (tables `articles` and `languages`).
Article `has_many languages` and Language `belongs_to article`.
I want to select articles with their languages.
I am using this in `Article` model:

```
def self.articles_per_page(limit, offset)
  joins("LEFT JOIN languages ON languages.article_id = articles.id")
  .select('articles.id, languages.language, COUNT(languages.id) as all_languages')
  .limit(limit).offset(offset)
  .group('articles.id, languages.language')
end
```

In the `articles_controller`:

```
def get_per_page
  limit = 40
  render json: Article.articles_per_page(limit, params[:offset])
end
```

Then I make `Ajax` request to get `JSON` response with articles and their languages:

```
$.get(articlesUrl + '?offset=' + offset, function(article){
    $.each(article, function(index, performance){
        $('#articleTable').append(// DATA //);
    });
            offset = $('#articleTable').children('.articleRow').length;
        })
```

The problem is that, if I have 1 article in `articles` table and for the example 3 languages associated with this article in the languages table, it returns 3 rows with same article.

Comment: so after you get this **active record association** you want this to be rendered in some views right?

Comment: Yes. I call this method in the controller `@articles = Article.articles_per_page(20, 0)`, then I am using it in the view.

Comment: How can a Language belong to an Article? No articles have the same language?

Comment: Another issue. Your query groups by article and language so it will obviously return 3 rows if there are 3 languages for the same articule. What do you really want to return with this query?

Comment: Lmao my 2 year old somehow posted an answer while I was eating lunch. What does the view look like? And what is the purpose of your `select()` and `group()`?

Comment: `select` is because I need to count languages `COUNT(languages.id) as all_languages`. group is because otherwise I am getting an error `Mysql2::Error: Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'languages.language' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by:`. The view is in the question

Answer (score 1):

Considering you wrote "I want to select articles with their languages." you could simply write that class method like:

```
def self.articles_per_page(limit, offset)
  includes(:languages).limit(limit).offset(offset)
end

@articles = Article.articles_per_page(10, 0)

= @articles.each do |article|
  = article.whatever
  = article.languages.each do |language|
    = language.whatever
  = article.languages.count # I'd add counter_cache
```

If all you need is the `count()` I would add a counter_cache column to articles model:

In language.rb

```
belongs_to :article, counter_cache: true
```

Then add `languages_count` to the article model and you can do stuff like:

```
= @articles.each do |article|
  = article.languages_count
```

How ever, with your select and group, I'm assuming you might be trying to add some sort of performance to your query? If that's the case knowing what your view looks like and the purpose of the select/group combo would help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The question was edited. I am using that query, because I am using `Ajax` to get `JSON response` with articles and their  language.

Comment: I mean  their languages.

Comment: I feel like the counter cache should help solve your problem. You'd just have to modify any frontend js to work with the new json object. Do you know what json your view is expecting to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem is because I am using `.group(articles.id, languages.language, ..)`, but without it I am getting an error:

> Mysql2::Error: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column '.articles.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by:

What I did is to remove `group(...)` and in the `config/database.yml`:

```
default: &default
    adapter: mysql2
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
    timeout: 5000
    username: database_user
    password: database_password
    variables:
        sql_mode: TRADITIONAL # THIS FIX THE PROBLEM
```

Then restart the server.